# sharepoint Manage regional settings and language settings of a site

Tags: sharepoint, regional-settings

I am working in a CRM application. Which is sharepoint-hosted App. I need to set regional setting in host web and set multiple language in App web programmatically. I want to do this by REST API or CSOM. If any body know, please tell me how can i do this?

Samaresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New api are available in new CSOM dll's. See if they what you need.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2015/04/10/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-office-365.aspx

Here’s the key changes in the released assemblies.

Manage regional settings of a site

Manage language settings of a site